# Qual é o atalho para execução de código no Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublime-text-2

Como faço para que o atalho `Ctrl(Cmd)+B` no Sublime Text, execute os códigos do Python na mesma tela do código?

Comment: Eu recomendo que você veja o Sublime REPL. Veja [esta questão](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input).

Comment: Eu coloquei ele mas ele abre uma aba tipo console para digitar os comandos ,o que eu queria era tipo assim:

http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/sem_titulo-png--4829/mostrar-codigo

Comment: Você tem que configurar o `build system`. Como diz na [documentação](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html).

Comment: Você salvou o arquivo com a extensão `.py`? Pelo que eu me lembre isso é tudo que você precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras de se fazer isso.

Eu geralmente aperto `CTRL+SHIFT+P` e digito até aparecer a opção `Build: With Python`.

Outra forma, é você selecionar `Tools > Build System >  Automatic`. Quando precisar rodar o `Build` padrão daquela extensão, você usa o atalho `CTRL+B`. 
Se você tiver mais de um `Build System` para mesma linguagem, a sugestão é aparecer `Ctrl+Shift+B`.

Aí vai aparecer uma lista de opções e você escolhe com qual `Build` você vai executar.

Comment: Boa Wallace, ajudou aqui, configurei o Python e um gerador de HTML baseado em arquivos .md +1

Answer (score 0):

É fácil, só seguir estes passos:

```
Tools > Build System > Automatic.
```

Feito isso, quando você precisar rodar aquela folder, basta dar o comando CTRL+B.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sua resposta esta idêntica a resposta do [Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/129182/3635) que é de 2016, quase 4 anos atrás.

Comment: Nem tinha percebido, vou fazer o que se esta é a resposta!